# Merge sparse data rows together grouped by the hour

Tags: r

A data.frame contains 2 columns with values. Each hour both columns contain a value and a NA, but never two values.

I'm looking for a way the merge two rows that have the same hour-day-month-year combination. Example:

```
# before
col1 col2 hour day month year
3    NA   1    3   2     2018  
NA   4    1    3   2     2018


#after
col1 col2 hour day month year
3    4    1    3   2     2018
```

I tried using methods form the `plyr` library (ddply, paste) and group by the `date` columns, but I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_by` and `summarise_all` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(year, month, day, hour) %>%
  summarise_all(sum, na.rm=TRUE)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   year, month, day [2]
   year month   day  hour  col1  col2
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  2018     2     3     1     3     4
2  2018     4     3     1     8     9
```

Data:

```
df
  col1 col2 hour day month year
1    3   NA    1   3     2 2018
2   NA    4    1   3     2 2018
3    8   NA    1   3     4 2018
4   NA    9    1   3     4 2018
```